# How to get the Order Id, Name and Email variables for a Shopper Approved survey?

Tags: variables

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
extensions from Amasty
subscribed to a Review service from Shopper Approved
```

We have been subscribed to the service from Shopper Approved for a long time. This allows our customers to rate us by filling out surveys. I haven't updated the code on our website since upgrading from Magento 1 to Magento 2. I called them today and they said it would be best if I was able to replace 3 variables in the code we are meant to put on the Check-out Confirmation page with the actual variables for:

- Order Id
- Name
- Email

**Where can I find these in Magento 2? Or if universal, what are they?**

---

UPDATED on January 19th, 2022:

The JavaScript code we were given by Shopper Approved to enter in on the Checkout Confirmation page is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var sa_values = { "site":12345, "token":"d138", 'orderid':'ORDER123', 'name':'John Doe', 'email':'john.doe@gmail.com' }; function saLoadScript(src) { var js = window.document.createElement("script"); js.src = src; js.type = "text/javascript"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js); } var d = new Date(); saLoadScript("https://www.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/23891.js?d=" + d.getTime()); </script>
```

Would I put that in like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var sa_values = { "site":12345, "token":"d138", '$orderId':'ORDER123', '$name':'John Doe', '$email':'john.doe@gmail.com' }; function saLoadScript(src) { var js = window.document.createElement("script"); js.src = src; js.type = "text/javascript"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js); } var d = new Date(); saLoadScript("https://www.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/23891.js?d=" + d.getTime()); </script>
```

or this?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var sa_values = { "site":12345, "token":"d138", 'orderid':'$orderId', 'name':'$name', 'email':'$email' }; function saLoadScript(src) { var js = window.document.createElement("script"); js.src = src; js.type = "text/javascript"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js); } var d = new Date(); saLoadScript("https://www.shopperapproved.com/thankyou/rate/23891.js?d=" + d.getTime()); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make good use of `OrderRepositoryInterface` to load the information you needed in any classes.

Here is the sample code:

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

class yourClass{

    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    ){
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function execute($orderId){
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
        $name = $order->getCustomerName();
        $email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
        //Rest of codes
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I've updated my post with the JavaScript code provided to us by Shopper Approved and my attempts to modify it. Am I heading in the right direction with this you think?

Comment: Your 2nd code is the answer already once this code is written in phtml template